# how to pronounce "butlerof" in american english? is /bɑːtlerɑːf/ true?

Tags: pronunciation

how to pronounce "butlerof" in american english?
is /bɑːtlerɑːf/ true?

> Mrs. Jencken's mediumship was interwoven in the texture of her daily
>   life. Professor **Butlerof** says that when he paid a morning social call
>   on her and her husband in company with M. Aksakof he heard raps upon
>   the floor.

from http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks03/0301051h.html

Comment: There is no general answer to how readers will pronounce an unfamiliar foreign name (or, indeed, an unfamiliar name). It depends on whether they recognise it as foreign, and its specific origin, and whether they are familiar with that language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically in American English, names are *supposed* to be pronounced according to their native pronunciation. So if 'Butlerof' is an alternative spelling of 'Butlerov,' it would be [boot-lay-rov](https://www.nameshouts.com/names/all-languages/pronounce-butlerov) or [boot-ler-rov](https://pronouncenames.com/search?name=Butlerov).

But that doesn't always happen.
As a native American my first guess was 'but-ler-off.'

Comment: I'm surprised by your first statement, because my experience of people with (in particular) East European names suggests that Americans are more likely to pronounce their names according to English spelling rules than British people with such names.

Comment: There are no *rules* in English for pronouncing names. Pronounce the name the way the person does.